# Receive large file by parts from webservice

Tags: web-services, pdf, download

I have a webservice that processes and dynamically generates a PDF file from several smaller files. I also have a client application (website) from which users can download the PDF file.
Sometimes the result PDF is very large, and because of memory and response time restrictions the website user is not able to download it.
I am trying to find a way to make my website receive smaller packages, or something like that, and gradually display it in the user browser. Something similar to a video stream, but with PDF files. Is there any way I can accomplish that?

*EDIT: I found [Mozilla's PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) a client-side PDF viewer built with HTML5 that I think would be useful to my issue, but I still haven't found in the docs how to solve the problem.
The solution proposed by Dan O would help me to improve the user experience, but not the memory problem in my server (webservice) and total time to process the PDF.

Answer (score 1):

use [HTTP chunking](https://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/#http1.1c2). Briefly:

1. set the `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header in your HTTP response
2. send your PDF file in chunks using the following format:

`<chunk size in bytes>
 \r\n
 <chunk of data>
 \r\n`

3. send an empty chunk to tell your user's browser that no more data is coming:

`0
 \r\n
 \r\n`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this will help me with the User Experience problem. But, from what I understood, my server will still need to process all at once, right? I will still have the memory use problem, because I will generate the entire PDF first, and then send it in chunks. It will also take a long time for the first chunk to be sent.